# Task in Activity Timeline

Tags: tasks, button, activity

[image]

In this new task in the RelatedTo, I have different objects(lookup relation given from task to each of the objects). This field RelatedTo I have to remove some objects but it is actually non-editable.

Is there some workaround to show only the objects I need in this section in the new task.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Validation Rule on the Task object that evaluates the first 3 characters of the WhatId (Record Id) and blocks the user from saving the record if they create a Task and try to relate it to one of those objects records.

The first 3 characters represent the object type that is related to.
Example Validation rule Formula:

```
AND(
LEFT( WhatId__c , 3) <> "001",
LEFT( WhatId__c , 3) <> "006")
```

Also, I suggest upvoting [this Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000H3xP7UAJ/disable-the-standard-object-when-selecting-a-related-to-from-the-whatid) so that it can be considered in coming releases

---

To remove the custom objects from the whatid lookup list try these steps:

1. Go to the object manager> select the object that you don't want to show in whatId field and Edit that.
2. Disable the "Allow Activities" checkbox that is in Optional Features.